# How to represent fields with generic types like List<Something> in swagger-spring-mvc for swagger-codegen

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I'm using swagger-spring-mvc 0.9.5 and have fields like this in my response data:

```
@ApiModelProperty("Some description")
private List<Account> accounts;
```

Short version of the question: **how can I get from this annotated Java to e.g. Objective C via swagger-codegen?**

The swagger JSON that gets generated by that is:

```
accounts: {
  description: "Some description",
  items: {
    type: "Account"
  },
  required: false,
  type: "List"
}
```

My colleague is feeding this into swagger-codegen to generate Objective C classes, and it's producing code that doesn't compile.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Optional, NSArray> *accounts;
```

because `NSArray` (inside the `< >`) isn't a protocol.

The swagger template files (mustache) create a protocol for each model. When that protocol is specified on an array, it is picked up by JSONModel to generate the correct models from the data inside the list / array. So in this case the expected output is

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Optional, MAAccount> *accounts;
```

This will create an `NSArray` of `MAAccount`'s (`Account` being the object type and `MA` being a prefix that swagger already has).

If we hand-edit the swagger JSON to change `List` to `array` (as suggested in various similar cases), the output is correct, but we want to avoid this manual step.

So I tried to get swagger-spring-mvc to use `"array"`:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Some description", dataType = "array")
private List<Account> accounts;
```

But then discovered that `dataType` is ignored in swagger-spring-mvc 0.9.5, and by the looks of it, in springfox 2.0 it is ignored unless it's a fully-qualified Java class name.

Is there a way to achieve this, either by getting swagger-spring-mvc/springfox to use `"array"` or by any other means?

Comment: You should try and move to 2.x of springfox. At the very least update your version to 1.0.2.

Comment: Yes, we're doing that, but I don't think that will help, will it? Specifically, I read that `dataType` will be ignored unless it's a fully-qualified class name.

Comment: Remove the annotation or at the very least remove datatype attribute (if you need to preserve the description) and it should do the right thing

Comment: Oh also to be codegen friendly setup the Docket with forCodeGeneration true

Comment: We need to keep the description, so we need the annotation. But will it generate `"array"` now instead of `"List"` if we omit `dataType`?`Will check out the flag, thanks (although we want to run swagger-ui from the same build, so that sounds a bit scary)

Comment: Yes it will :) about the swagger-ui question, it will absolutely work, only it won't look like a generic class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part the swagger annotations are only an aid to the springfox engine to infer additional information about the types like description/hidden/readonly etc that are not otherwise available from the type system. It can also used as a crutch to represent types that are not easily inferred. Data types can be overriden, but just for type safety as it was pointed out in the comment.

> Specifically, I read that dataType will be ignored unless it's a fully-qualified class name.

Like @CupawnTae suggested, [version 2.x of springfox](http://springfox.io) supports an option to render generic types with code-generation friendly and language agnostic representations of generic types.

When creating/configuring your docket you will need to specify that the rendered swagger service description needs to be code-generation friendly using the `forCodeGeneration` option

```java
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      ...
      .forCodeGeneration(true)
      ...;
}
```

This will cause springfox to render generic types like `List<String>`

- as `ListOfString` when `forCodeGeneration` is set to true
- as `List«String»` when `forCodeGeneration` is set to false

Comment: Hi, I am trying this solution but it didn't work. I want to render a variable with type String to List<String>. I have dataType in ApiModelProperty as "List<String>", but it will just render String anyway. Seems it is still igonring the dataType field...

Answer (score 0):

You can try notation below. Dont't forget to use package info of you class

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "[Lyour.package.Account;")
private List<Account> accounts;
```